# number of homomorphisms from a group to another

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

how do I find the number of homomorphisms from one group G1 to another group G2
does it matter if G1 and G2 are not cyclic? 
for example there is a question that says:
how many homomorphisms are there from Z20 to Z16?
the answer is 4 but how do I get them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For general groups $G_1$ and $G_2$, this can be a quite challenging problem.

In your particular case, however, you can reason as follows. A homomorphism $\phi$ from $\mathbb Z_{20}$ to $\mathbb Z_{16}$ is completely determined by specifying where the image of the generator $z$ of $\langle z \rangle \cong \mathbb Z_{20}$ maps to. The only condition is that $z^{20}$, which is trivial in $\mathbb Z_{20}$, must map into a trivial element. This amounts to $\phi(z^{20}) = \phi(z)^{20}$ being trivial. In the group $\mathbb Z_{16}$, this is the same as requiring $\phi(z)^4$ being trivial. Now, the latter condition means that $z$ must map into an element in $\mathbb Z_{16}$ whose order divides $4$. You can check that there are precisely $4$ such elements: $\{ 0, 4, 8, 12 \}$.

Comment: I am working on a problem where I need to show there are multiple homomorphisms between one group and another. I also chose to use cyclic groups. I understand what you're saying about the trivial elements need to map to other trivial elements, this is for being well-defined, if I'm not mistaken. So is your example here, what would those homomorphisms actually look like by definition? For example, mapping the trivial to 0, would look like this? $f:Z/20Z \to Z/16Z;\ f(z) = 6z$?

Comment: If you pick $\phi(z) = 0$, then $\phi(z^n) = \phi(z)^n = 0$ for all $n$, and so $\phi$ maps everything to $0$. If, on the other hand, you pick $\phi(z) = 4$, then $\phi(z^n) = \phi(z)^n = 4^n$. Using additive notation, this means that $\phi(n) = 4n$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{16}$.